# Get domain UserName for computer that not in domain

Tags: c#

I hope somebody could help me to solve my problem.

There is some domain, and some shared directory in that domain. User has domain username and password, to get access to that shared directory, but his computer is not in domain most of time. I mean, when he need to connect to that directory he is typing network path (for example "\\fileserver"), than windows asks for username and password, and after writing it he will get the access until restart windows or logout.

So my question is, how can i get domain user name that user uses to connect to network, by using C# code?

I tryed to use CredentialCache.GetCredential, but i think it works only if user connect to shared directory by using NetworkCredentials in C# program. If connection already was before C# program started, it will be empty.
I also tryed Environment.UserName, but since computer is not in domain, it returns only local user name, that different from domain username.

Sorry for my bad english, i hope you could understand my explanation.

Comment: Add the computer to the domain. Even if it's a laptop, domain login will still work. Typing a network path doesn't mean the user connected to a domain. What you call user is the *user account*. That's what was used to log into the machine. If it's a local account, it's a local account. When the user tried to access a file share they just accessed a file share using some credentials, they didn't change their account

Comment: This is actually a *administration question*, not a programming question. Windows/Active Directory supports occasionally connected machines for decade**s** - branch offices may use slow lines to connect to HQ. Remote user laptops may only connect once a week.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Thank you for you answer. I understand that user not become part of domain when he typing network path, but just use some credentials. That exactly what i want to know: how i can get this credential. I just think, that if there is no need to enter login\pass every time for get access to shared directory, that means this credentials stored somewhere until windows is restarted. So, maybe it could be extracted from this storage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you took a look at the nugget package [CredentialManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/) ?

I used it already, but couldn't roam credential saved with enterprise persistence

```
using CredentialManagement;

using (CredentialSet credentials = new CredentialSet())
{
    Debug.Print(credentials.Count.ToString() + " credential(s) found.");
    foreach (Credential credential in credentials)
    {
        Debug.Print(credential.Target); //This is domain/IP of the saved credential.
        Debug.Print(credential.Type.ToString());
        Debug.Print(credential.Username);
        Debug.Print(credential.PersistanceType.ToString());
        Debug.Print(credential.Description);
        Debug.Print(credential.LastWriteTime.ToString());
    }
    Debug.Print("End");
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for answer, yes i tryed it too. It shows 0 credentials found. Seems like it works, only if credential was created by programm, but not manually entered by user.

Comment: When you are going to the credential vault manually, what is the persistence of the saved credentials?

Comment: it's Enterprise as i see.

Comment: You can't retrieve saved credentials with enterprise persistence. I had the same issue.